# How to print Json data in ng-repeat using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to print the json data in angularjs using ng-repeat. In ng-repeat I only want to print for example **"data": [{"y":"23","x": "12"}]** please see the json data. But it print nothing in html.

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/zy1C2z39dXuuHDx8eqxK?p=preview

**JSON Data**

```
{"series": [{"meter": "instance", "data": [{"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-21T14:21:33"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-22T14:21:34"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-23T14:21:34"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-24T14:23:39"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-25T14:23:39"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-26T02:43:39"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-27T14:24:33"}], "name": "demo", "unit": "instance"}], "settings": {}}
```

**Angularjs**

```
 app.controller('ceilometerCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering")
      .success(function(response) {                    
         $scope.metrics=response.series[0].data;              
       });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ceilometerCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="metric in metrics">
        Metric: {{metric.x}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Result** nothing is printing

```
Metric:
Metric:
Metric:
Metric:
Metric:
Metric:
Metric:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes in your code.

1. As `series` is an array, update from

   ```
   $scope.metrics=response.series.data;
   ```

to

```
$scope.metrics=response.series[0].data;
```

2. `x` and `y` are properties of metric. Update from

   ```
    Metric: {{metric.data.x}}
   ```

to

```
 Metric: {{metric.x}}
```

Comment: @nikhil, see the question again, I tried but is giving nothing, plz see the result

Comment: @NeelabhSingh Make sure you're using `metric.x` instead `matric.data.x`

Comment: @nikhil please see the link http://plnkr.co/edit/zy1C2z39dXuuHDx8eqxK?p=preview  I followed same procedure as you told to do

Comment: You did not injected $http. I have updated the plunker. For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/zLuDs84IdmRxmKjrwsk8?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    <div ng-repeat="metric in metrics">
      Metric X :  {{metric.x}}
      Metric Y :  {{metric.y}}
   </div>
```

and in controller. Change this line

```
$scope.metrics=response.series.data;
```

to

```
$scope.metrics=response.series[0].data;
```

Your `Json` is valid. You were only doing wrong in `ng-repeat`. Above snippet will work in your case.

Comment: It is an `array of objects`.

Comment: please see the link http://plnkr.co/edit/zy1C2z39dXuuHDx8eqxK?p=preview  I followed same procedure as you told to do

Answer (score 0):

Its easier than that depending on what your data looks like just use the "json" filter.  In your case you might need to do `response.series[0].data;` as mentioned above but once you have what you want to use as data it should be as simple as:

```
    Metric: <pre>{{metrics.series[0].data|json}}</pre>
```

Simple fiddle showing : http://jsfiddle.net/hLf1rLxz/

---

Updated per your request.  Your plunkr was broken.  The d3 reference was missing d3.time I updated it to a temporary one.  Next up was `RickSha` was throwing an error.  I moved $scope.series above the `new RickShaw` and was able to get the pre to work.
Updated fiddle:  http://plnkr.co/edit/iMB4ElKqfAlM0wdyqpA7?p=preview

Code required:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <pre>{{metrics | json}}</pre>

   <div id="chart"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: please see the link http://plnkr.co/edit/zy1C2z39dXuuHDx8eqxK?p=preview  I want to use http

Comment: @NeelabhSingh see above .  I did not fix your rickshaw issue.  you can figure that one out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter `json`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json):

```
{{ your.data | json }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have written above i.e.

```
$scope.metrics=response.series.data;
```

your $scope.metrics will be undefined, since response.series is an array, not a JSON object.

There are two approaches that can be applied

**Case 1:**

```
app.controller('ceilometerCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get("http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering")
    .success(function(response) {
      /**
       * now your response is
       * {"series": [{"meter": "instance", "data": [{"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-21T14:21:33"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-22T14:21:34"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-23T14:21:34"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-24T14:23:39"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-25T14:23:39"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-26T02:43:39"}, {"y": 1.0, "x": "2015-07-27T14:24:33"}], "name": "demo", "unit": "instance"}], "settings": {}}
       * doing response.series will give you an array
       * [{"meter": "instance","data": [{  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-21T14:21:33"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-22T14:21:34"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-23T14:21:34"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-24T14:23:39"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-25T14:23:39"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-26T02:43:39"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-27T14:24:33"}],"name": "demo","unit": "instance"}]
       * first you will have to iterate over each object of a series. and then iterate over data object from each item on the for loop :) 
       * <div ng-repeat="s in series">
       *   <div ng-repeat="d in s.data">
       *     {{ d.x }} <br />
       *     {{ d.y }}
       *   </div>
       * </div>
       */
      $scope.series = response.series; // apply the ng-repeat twice, as described above :)
    });
});
```

if you are into copy-paste, this will be your html

```
<div ng-repeat="s in series">
  <div ng-repeat="d in s.data">
    {{ d.x }} <br />
    {{ d.y }}
  </div>
</div>
```

**Case 2:**

Get the first element from your response

```
app.controller('ceilometerCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering")
    .success(function(response) {
      /**
       * getting the first element from the response, which is an array, will give you
       * a json object i.e.
       * { "meter": "instance","data": [{  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-21T14:21:33"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-22T14:21:34"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-23T14:21:34"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-24T14:23:39"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-25T14:23:39"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-26T02:43:39"}, {  "y": 1.0,  "x": "2015-07-27T14:24:33"}],"name": "demo","unit": "instance" }
       * now you just iterate of the data series
       * <div ng-repeat="d in matrics.data">
       *     {{ d.x }} <br />
       *     {{ d.y }}
       * </div>
       */
      $scope.matrics = response.series[0];
    });
});
```

the html in second case would simply be

```
<div ng-repeat="d in matrics.data">
  {{ d.x }} <br />
  {{ d.y }}
</div>
```

hope this helps.